# Create overall controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The frame of my application looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'sources/includes/home.html',
        controller : 'homeController'
    })
    .when('/about-us',{
        templateUrl: 'sources/includes/about-us.html',
        controller : 'aboutUsController'
    })
    .when('/catalog',{
        templateUrl: 'sources/includes/catalog.html',
        controller : 'catalogController'
    })
    .when('/sale',{
        templateUrl: 'sources/includes/sale.html',
        controller : 'saleController'
    })
    .when('/info',{
        templateUrl: 'sources/includes/info.html',
        controller : 'infoController'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  });
```

I need to create an overall controller which will set the same behavior for all its views

I tried something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'sources/includes/home.html',
    controller : 'homeController'
  })
  .when('/about-us',{
    templateUrl: 'sources/includes/about-us.html',
    controller : 'aboutUsController'
    controller : 'overallController'
  })
  .when('/catalog',{
    templateUrl: 'sources/includes/catalog.html',
    controller : 'catalogController',
    controller : 'overallController'
  })
  .when('/sale',{
    templateUrl: 'sources/includes/sale.html',
    controller : 'saleController',
    controller : 'overallController'
  })
  .when('/info',{
    templateUrl: 'sources/includes/info.html',
    controller : 'infoController',
    controller : 'overallController'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  });

  // O V E R A L L  C O N T R O L L E R
  app.controller('overallController', function ($scope){

  });
```

Any ideas how can I set the same behavior for that four views?

Comment: you are going on wrong approach

Comment: @Rituraj ratan I understand it, but trying to find right solution

Comment: what kind of behaviour do you want those views to have? perhaps there is another way to solve your problem?

Comment: I think that you are looking for **directive** than can be put on main file like `index.html`. What kind of behavior are you going to implement?

Comment: for example views about-us, catalog, sale and info has the same script which must calculate the height of this views - I can put this code to each view and it will works, but I don't wont to dublicate the code course I think must be the way how to make it overall

Comment: If you want each controllers for each of routes and a global controller for the page, You might want to try `app.run(function($rootScope){ ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controllers are JS constructors; you could implement what you want with mixins:

```
app.service("overallBehaviour", function() {

    var overallBehaviour = {};

    overallBehaviour.commonMethod = function() {
        ...
    };

    return overallBehaviour;
});
```

Then:

```
app.controller("aboutUsController", ["$scope", "overallBehaviour", function($scope, overallBehaviour) {
    angular.extend(this, overallBehaviour);
    // now this controller has access to overallBehaviour.commonMethod()

}]);
```

---

**The difference between `angular.extend(this,...)` and `angular.extend($scope, ...)`:**

1. `angular.extend(this,...)` will mix the object into the controller; the methods, e.g. `commonMethod()` will be available in the controller as usual. These methods *will NOT* be available to the `$scope` (and the views) unless additional steps are involved, e.g. using the `controllerAs` syntax. The common methods will be available to the controller. The `this` in these methods will be the controller.
2. `angular.extend($scope, ...)` will make the methods directly available to the scope (and the view). `this` in the methods will be the scope.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken the array ["$scope",... mast be closed somewhere

Comment: but look like it should!

Comment: It works. Nice approach with mixins.
@fresa http://plnkr.co/edit/B7WaAIlTJnh49j2wcjyU?p=preview

Comment: Yes, the array should absolutely be closed :)